# How do I make stat_smooth work in ggplot-python?

Tags: python, plot, ggplot2, pandas, python-ggplot

That's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio
from ggplot import *
from db import conn

sql = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE time > (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day')::date"
df = sqlio.read_frame(sql, conn)
conn.close()

lng = pd.melt(df[['time', 'players', 'servers']], id_vars='time')
plt = ggplot(aes(x='time', y='value', colour='variable'), data=lng) + \
        geom_line() + \
        stat_smooth(colour='red', se=True) + \
        ggtitle('Players and servers online over last 24h') + \
        xlab("Time of the day") + \
        ylab("Amount")
ggsave(filename="day.svg", plot=plt)
```

This is what the code generates:

[result http://zduniak.net/wV9S6](http://zduniak.net/wV9S6)

The history table has 3 columns:

- time - datetime
- players - integer
- servers - integer

What I want is two smooth red lines drawn over black and orange ones. Somehow stat_smooth doesn't work at all. How can I make it work?

Comment: I can't help you wit the `ggplot` stuff, unfortunately. But I thought you might like to know that with a current version of pandas, you can simply do `pd.read_sql(sql, conn)`. Not terribly important, but it's nice.

Comment: my guess is that its an incompatibility in the date format. can you post some of the `lng` dataframe?

Comment: Somehow code works in production on an Ubuntu Server, but doesn't in VM on Ubuntu. I have **no idea** what's happening.

Comment: There have been a lot of updates to ggplot since this was originally asked. Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed as per these issues:

https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/pull/43

https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/pull/170