# What do I need to do using IPython and ggplot to get legends on multiple time-series plot?

Tags: python, ipython, python-ggplot

I am trying to learn how to use the ggplot library in python. In
familiarizing myself with some of the examples, I noticed that to get a
time series plot of several series, it seems to be necessary to
`pandas.melt()` the data into long form.

Using
[Is there a way to plot a pandas series in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541497/is-there-a-way-to-plot-a-pandas-series-in-ggplot)
as a model, I am playing with the meat data set in ggplot. Although the
display of the data seems to be ok, there is no legend. The prescription
for fixing the legend at the bottom of the link fails in my example.

Somewhere I saw a post that suggests that the legend display only fails
inline (in an IPython notebook). For me it also failed to display the
legend using qt (on a Mac).

```
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
```

The 'meat' data frame in its original form.

```
print meat.head (2)

        date  beef  veal  pork  lamb_and_mutton  broilers  other_chicken  \
0 1944-01-01   751    85  1280               89       NaN            NaN   
1 1944-02-01   713    77  1169               72       NaN            NaN   

   turkey  
0     NaN  
1     NaN
```

The 'meat' data frame in long form.

```
meat_lng = pd.melt(meat, id_vars=['date'])
print meat_lng.head (2)

        date variable  value
0 1944-01-01     beef    751
1 1944-02-01     beef    713

plot = ggplot(aes(x='date', y='value', color='variable'), data=meat_lng) \
     + geom_line() \
     + ggtitle("Meat Production by Decade--Missing Legend")
print plot
```

.. image:: output_6_0.png

```
<ggplot: (280905345)>
```

I have the graph in PNG format. How can I insert it here?

I hoped the few lines at the bottom would get me a legend.

```
plot = ggplot(aes(x='date', y='value', color='variable'), data=meat_lng) \
     + geom_line(size=2.0) \
     + ggtitle("Meat Production by Decade")

# Code that I hoped would fix the missing legend problem.
fig = plot.draw()
ax = fig.axes[0]
offbox = ax.artists[0]
offbox.set_bbox_to_anchor((1, 0.5), ax.transAxes)
fig.show()
```

::

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-9cd7998d1503> in <module>()
      4 fig = plot.draw()
      5 ax = fig.axes[0]
----> 6 offbox = ax.artists[0]
      7 offbox.set_bbox_to_anchor((1, 0.5), ax.transAxes)
      8 fig.show()


IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I have exactly this problem - it is completely mysterious to me.

Comment: I have discussed this with some people pretty familiar with matplotlib. They thought originally that it was a bug in matplotlib. I have found some references that say it was fixed. I think that the ggplot author thinks it is a matplotlib bug. The main author of matplotlib died 2 years ago and it looks like the last work done on this problem might have been around Dec 2013. I don't think the marked code should be needed, but in any event, if it once fixed the problem, it no longer does.

Comment: Same problem. Still not fixed? Python ggplot graphs without legends render the whole package a bit deficient.

Answer (score 1):

The example you're referencing was done using ggplot version 0.5.8.  Something they changed in the later versions removed the legend from the scatterplot. There is an open issue concerning this on ggplot's github page but until its resolved, if you want the legend to appear I would recommend using the older version.